# CUDA with invoking virtual methods in kernel on objects that was created on Host

Tags: c++, class, cuda, virtual

Description of my problem is in this code below.

```
class A
{
public :
        __device__ __host__ virtual void foo() = 0;
        __device__ __host__ void foo2()
        {
                //something to do...
        }
};

class B : public A
{
public :
        __device__ __host__ B()
        { }
        //implementing virtual method foo from A
        void foo()
        {
                //something to do...
        }
};

__global__ void Test(A* ptr_device)
{
        ptr_device->foo2(); //it's okey
        ptr_device->foo(); //ERROR !!!
}

void main()
{
        B* b_host = new B();

        A* a_host = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
        memcpy(a_host, b_host, sizeof(A));

        a_host->foo();
        a_host->foo2();
        //it's okey

        A* a_device;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&a_device, sizeof(A));
        cudaMemcpy(a_device, a_host, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        Test<<<1, 1>>>(a_device);
}
```

The problem is when I want to invoke a virtual method of class A on kernel.
First I'm creating a object B, then mallocing space for A object and copying B to A.
On Host code it works fine but in Device code it gets an error in invoking foo method

Comment: Please paste the code into the question... And while at it, please clarify the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just `memcpy` non-POD objects around and expect them to work, you invoke quite some UB here.

What happens in your case is likely that the object has some virtual table pointer that gets copied over, but has no meaning within that other execution environment as it almost certainly will not point to the virtual table that exists there (given it there is even one).

Comment: So, how should I do safer copy of B stored in A ?

Comment: basically I want create object B on Host and safely transfer to kernel in A "container", with all overridden methods.

Comment: @waskithebest: I don't know enough of CUDA, but the only thing I can imagine is to copy some POD data into a place where the kernel can reach it, and let the kernel create an object on its own that uses this data to initialize itself. You will not be able to memcopy objects with virtual functions and have the virtual functions behave correctly.

Comment: Ok - found "It is not allowed to pass as an argument to a __global__ function an object of a class with virtual functions.

The virtual function table is placed in global or constant memory by the compiler."